# EVM OPCODES gas cost source file

Tags: evm, gas-estimate

Where can I find the source code file where the EVM extracts the gas cost of all OPCODES?
What I need is the file where the EVM calculates the gas cost of SLOAD, ADD, etc.
For example, hardhat-gas-reporter plugin is able to calculate the gas cost of a smart contract's functions. From where do they get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find gas prices that [Hardhat](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat) uses from [ethereumjs-monorepo](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/tree/master/packages/common).

For instance, `DELEGATECALL` opcode was introduced with HomeStead hardfork, and the base fee is found [here](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/blob/master/packages/common/src/hardforks/homestead.json).

I'm assuming that these gas fees are referenced from [the yellowpaper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) and additional EIPs are drawn from the Ethereum Github repository. e.g. [EIP-7(homestead hardfork)](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-7.md).